# Proving integrability of pathological function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $A'$ and $A''$ be compact subsets of $\mathbb R$, and call $A = A' \times A''$. Let $\{x_n'\}$ be a sequence whose image is $\mathbb Q \cap A'$, and let $d$ be the Dirichlet function
$$d : A'' \to \mathbb R \qquad d(x'') = \begin{cases}1 & x'' \in \mathbb Q \cap A'' \\ 0 & x'' \in A'' \setminus \mathbb Q \end{cases} $$
Now define
$$f : A \to \mathbb R \qquad f(x',x'') = \begin{cases} \dfrac 1 n d(x'') & x'=x'_n \\ 0 & x' \in A' \setminus\mathbb Q\end{cases} $$
One cannot be certain of the integrability of $x' \mapsto f(x', \cdot)$, which can either be the null function or a scaled version of $d$, and yet $f$ is integrable over $A$ and its integral is zero.

How would I prove this fact? My take is I'd need to show that $\forall \varepsilon > 0$ there is a stepfunction $s : A \to \mathbb R$ such that
$$s \geq f, \qquad \int_A s\ dm \leq \varepsilon$$
but I can't think of a way to construct such an $s$, although I guess that at some point the (obvious) statement
$$\exists n^\dagger \in \mathbb N : \forall n \geq n^\dagger \quad \frac 1 n \leq \varepsilon $$
should come into play and let me cap that integral with $\varepsilon m(A)$.